# Uninstalling 2 instances on one node in a 2 node SQL Server 2012 cluster

Tags: sql-server-2012, cluster-computing, database-administration

I need some pointers to uninstalling 2 instances on SQL Server 2012 cluster

We have a **SQLl2012 Active -Active cluster** with **instance A on Node 1** and **Instance B, Instance C and 3 services on Node 2**. I need to uninstall Instance A and B from Node2. The services could be removed/disabled.So I will have an Active-Active cluster with Instance C on Node 1 and no instance on Node2.

I have never uninstalled an instance on a cluster and we don’t have any test system so I have a couple of questions.

**1**. When there is no instance on Node 2, does it become an Active Passive cluster?

**2**. Do I have to take the node offline before the uninstall?

**3**. Can I get any links to uninstalling an instance? I have googled but have only come up with uninstalling nodes. I got one that said about uninstalling an instance but at the end of it, uninstalled the node. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2172/uninstalling-a-sql-server-clustered-instance/

**4**. Am I right in understanding that you need the installation media to uninstall the instance? And that I cannot use uninstall programme method for this?

**5**. I have a link below with a comment from Perry Whittle.https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1470694-1550-1.aspx So does it mean if I use the remove node option , it will remove only the instance  BUT the node will still be there ?

I had initially disabled the 2 instances on the node ,thinking that would be a safer option but that gave rise to continuous alerts on our Nagios monitoring system and Operations got errors during the monthly patching.

Thanks

Comment: You should probably ask this question on [Database Admnistrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks Andrea, i have just done that.